Docker not using proxies within Python script
I'm facing an issue where my Python script using the requests library work fine outside of Docker. But inside
Docker it doesn't seem to use the proxy to make the request. It also doesn't throw any errors.
Found just this post which seems to have the same issue but no responses unfortunately. I couldn't find anything else at all regarding this issue. Can't imagine I am the only since my setup is fairly simple as well.
I have also tried adding the proxies as ENV variables, but that also didn't work.
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates openssl

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT"

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]

Python
import requests

def proxy_request():
    proxies = {
        "http": "http://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT",
        "https": "http://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT",
    }
    response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', proxies=proxies)
    print("Status:", response.status_code)
    print("Content:", response.text)

Again, outside of Docker the response return the IP of the proxy. However, inside Docker it returns my own IP.
I have tried multiple Python libraries; requests & httpx. They both have the same issue.
aiohttp didn't work at all due to a SSL issue.

Can you run docker history --no-trunc your_image_id > resutl.txt   and post the results? Also remember to hide your USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT from the output as well.

@LNTR Thanks for you reply. I tested the exact same setup on other windows & linux machines which worked fine. I decided to uninstall Docker Desktop which solved the issue. No idea what the underlying issue was but it's solved now.

Same thing happened to me few days ago. In my case docker was adding additional layers from another image even though I'm sure I did not do such a thing. So I deleted the image that causing the problem(The actual image of the unnecessary layer) and rebuild my previous image. Then it started working as I expected.
